# How to load data in 'type:select' of appendGrid control of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I know by using json we can  load data to appendGrid control, and even I am able to load data dynamically in ''type:textarea''.
But want to load data in list of appendgrid i.e''type:select''.
How to load it?

Instead of hard coding values for select i want it to give from java /Ajax.
Code:

$('#tblAppendGrid').addClass('alternate');
$(

'#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
caption :

'Add/Edit Product',
initRows : 1,

columns : [ {

name :

'LOB',
display :

'LOB',
type :

'select',
ctrlOptions : {

0 :

'1',
1 :

'2'
}

Comment: Do you have an example of code ?

Comment: Please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

You don't close correctly your JSON parameter :

```js
$('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
    caption : 'Add/Edit Product',
    initRows : 1,
    columns : [
      { name : 'LOB', display : 'LOB', type : 'select', ctrlOptions : { 0 : '1', 1 : '2' }}
    ]
});
```